# How to delete orphaned profile in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, onedrive-for-business

For an unknown reason SharePoint Online keeps creating the personal website of one of my users with the suffix "1".

#### What I want to achieve

I want to have the users personal website at:
- https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/j_doe_contoso_com
instead of
- https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/j_doe_contoso_com1

#### What I tried

In the *SharePoint Admin Center* I deleted the user profile for user `i:0#.f|membership|j.doe@contoso.com` and let SharePoint recreate the profile and personal website by just logging in at https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com. This then redirects to the *MyBraryFirstRun* page. However, the wizard recreates the personal website with the suffix.

In the *SharePoint Admin Center* I also tried to remove the suffix from the path to the personal website in the users profile settings. When I then visit https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com the *MyBraryFirstRun* does not show. Instead I see a read-only version of an empty personal website.

#### What I think is the problem

I assume there is an orphaned personal website */personal/j_doe_contoso_com* thus John Doe's pesonal website is created with a suffix. If I assume correctly, I would need to delete both personal websites and upon visiting https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com, the correct personal website should be created at https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/j_doe_contoso_com.

#### What I think is the solution

So I guess what I need to do is to delete both profiles
- https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/j_doe_contoso_com1
**and**
- https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/j_doe_contoso_com

#### Where I struggle

The *SharePoint Admin Center* does not seem to offer that possibility.

The PowerShell does not seem to offer that possibility via cmdlets.

It *seems* that with the PowerShell I have more power when loading some DLLs or what like so: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.…")` But that exceeds my skills.

I hope to find some help on the matter.

Comment: You want to remove sites through powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check what's the URL of the personal site of a user. Follow below steps

1. Login to SharePoint admin center
2. Go to User profiles > Manage User Profiles > Search for your user
3. Go to edit profile page. Check what's in `Personal Site`.

If you want to delete user's personal site then use following command

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/j_doe_contoso_com
```

Comment: Wow, I know about `Get-SPOSite` but it never listed the personal sites, so I could not know that I'd be able to remove them with `Remove-SPOSite`. This totally solved my problem!

Comment: @Daniel Even I had same impression :). But using this command I have removed many personal sites.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to list *all* personal sites? There is a way to [list *active* personal sites](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn911464.aspx) and it works, but it didn't show the orphaned `/personal/j_doe_contoso_com` (without the suffix) though.

Comment: @Daniel I am afraid I am not aware about it. Its an interesting topic for research though.